# Is there any authentication method on client id and the operation

Tags: ibm-datapower

Is there any idea for the below requirement

I’ve soap ws with three operations add, delete and update. It needs to authenticate Two things
First client id that will be sent in request body using AAA action if true then second will check the privilege on allowed operations for that client

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `Custom AAA` stylesheet and do multiple checks in it. Another option would be to run multiple AAA actions after one another but I'd go for the `Custom Stylesheet`...

See this quick sample here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/authentication-customization-websphere-datapower-aaa-policy